# Android Xamarin AAR Binding enclosing type

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-binding-adapter

I have an `.aar` third party library that I want to use in Xamarin Android. So I created a new `Android Bindings Library`, added the `aar`-library and changed the `Build action` of the `aar` file to `LibraryProjectZip` like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

Nothing else was changed and I would expect the project to compile and generate a `dll` file.
Instead I get a lot of errors saying `Error CS0542  'xy': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`.
When I jump to the origin of the error, I find the errors in generated code by Visual Studio with the classes looking something like:

```
public abstract class Albumin : Java.Lang.Object {

    internal Albumin ()
    {
    }

    // (removed for readability)
    [Register ("ALBUMIN")]
    public const string Albumin = (string) "albumin";
```

I cannot modify the source code of the library.
What can I do in order to build the `Binding Library` successfully?

Comment: You could try to [Renaming Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#renaming-members).

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much @Leo Zhu for the answer in the comments:

The solution is [Renaming Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#renaming-members).
So in my case the `Metadata.xml` in die `Binings Library` would look like the following:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.company.android.sdk.dataclass']/interface[@name='DataClass.Albumin']/field[@name='ALBUMIN']" name="name">ALBUMIN_Binding</attr>
```